# Timeout issue on ASP.NET MVC4 and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the following timeout error in one of our ASP.NET MVC applications. Below is the stack trace.

What's weird is that the user gets the error after only about 5 seconds she clicks the button that calls a LINQ query. But if she tries clicking the button a second time, after about a minute, the report appears and everything is ok.

The fact that she gets the error after only 5 seconds on the first attempt tells me that this is not a timeout issue...or is it? The LINQ query is a little complex but it works fine when she clicks the button the second time. Any suggestions what this might be?

Here is the code (the LINQ query) that causes the timeout:

```
    private List<ProductionReportExcelWriter.ProductLine> GetProductList(ProductionReporViewInput input)
    {
        return _context.Set<Product>()
            .Include(p => p.Dough)
            .Include(oi => oi.OrderItems)
            .Include(oi => oi.OrderItems.Select(o => o.Order))
            .Include(oi => oi.OrderItems.Select(o => o.Order.Client))
            .AsQueryable()
            .ForNextOrderDate(input.ReportDate)
            .WithActiveClients()
            .ForOrdersItemsWithQuantities()
            .WithoutHiddenProducts().ToList()
            .Select(p => new ProductionReportExcelWriter.ProductLine
            {
                ProductId = p.Id,
                Dough = p.Dough.Name,
                ProductCode = p.ProductCode,
                DoughPosition = p.Dough.Position,
                Description = p.Description,
                Weight = p.Weight,
                Account = p.Account,
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Error message:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Complete stack trace:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)  
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)  
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)  
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)  
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)  
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)  
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)  
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)  
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)  
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)  
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetResults>b__2()  
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)  
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetResults>b__1()  
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)  
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)  
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()  
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()  
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)  
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)  
at Arhoma.Core.Views.ProductionReportViewFactory.GetProductList(ProductionReporViewInput input) in C:\Projects\webapp-commande\core-commande\Views\ProductionReportViewFactory.cs:line 66
at Arhoma.Core.Views.ProductionReportViewFactory.CreateProductionReportExcelWriterModel(ProductionReporViewInput input) in C:\Projects\webapp-commande\core-commande\Views\ProductionReportViewFactory.cs:line 37
at Arhoma.Core.Views.ProductionReportViewFactory.Load(ProductionReporViewInput input) in C:\Projects\webapp-commande\core-commande\Views\ProductionReportViewFactory.cs:line 26
at Arhoma.Core.ViewRepositoryOutputBuilder`1.Using[TInput](TInput input) in C:\Projects\webapp-commande\core-commande\ViewRepository.cs:line 42
at Arhoma.WebApp.Controllers.ClosingController.ProductionReport(Nullable`1 date) in C:\Projects\webapp-commande\webapp-commande\Controllers\ClosingController.cs:line 47
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: how about posting the code that causes the exception?

Comment: I added the linq query that is causing the timeout.

Comment: I would wrap this in a try..catch..finally and take a look at any inner exceptions that are available. Also try simplifying the LINQ to see if that shows anything up. Also I don't think the comma (,) after p.Account shouldn't be there and I'm surprised it's compiling.

Comment: `.AsQueryable()` is useless because it execute your query in memory and not on the server side. Remove it and all will be OK.

Comment: You should profile the generated query by EF on your provider directly and see what it does. You can see what it is using a Profiler Tool (like Sql Profiler for Sql Server). You should be looking at how long it takes to complete manually, what the execution plan is, and if there are spots for improvement either in the query, schema, or by adding db objects like indexes.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Can you explain why you think removing AsQueryable() will fix the timeout issue.

Comment: I think the problem is the first .ToList() on line 12. This will execute the statement before selecting the fields. Probably all fields of all included tables are returned causing the timeout. You'll only need one .ToList(). The last one, after selecting the fields.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config file where connection string tag is written there, increase timeout like that do it Timeout=200 or Timeout=500.
 for example-

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa@123;Connect Timeout=200" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: I don't think that'll increase the timeout for the command or query. I think that's the timeout for the connection. That's not the problem I'm having.